# RTRIM in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. In my table below I'm trying to get rid of the ID numbers from 1st Jan 2019 to 4th Jan 2019 that are 5 digits long or after the dash begin with a zero.

```
IDnum        DateTime
-----------------------
11-102434    03/01/2019    
11-02434     03/01/2019 
11-102421    02/01/2019
11-02421     02/01/2019
10-02345     31/12/2018
```

This is what I would like to see

```
IDnum        DateTime
-------------------------
11-102434    03/01/2019    
11-102421    02/01/2019
10-02345     31/12/2018
```

I'm thinking there needs to be some kind of `RTRIM()` in the where clause but not sure how to do this.

Comment: So, what SQL have you already written and how does it fail to do what you want?

Comment: Do all IDnum's start with two digits and a dash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way.

```
SELECT IDnum, DateTime
  FROM YourTable
 WHERE NOT (DateTime >= '2019-01-01' AND DateTime < '2019-01-05' --exclude from 1st Jan 2019 to 4th Jan 2019
             AND (IDnum LIKE '%-_____'  --that are 5 digits long after the dash
                  OR 
                  IDnum LIKE '%-0%'  --or begin with a 0 (after the dash)
                 )
           )
```

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this a relatively simple `where` clause?

```
where not (datetime >= '2019-01-01' and datetime < '2019-01-05' and
           (idnum like '%-_____' or
            idnum like '%-0%'
           )
          )
```

Comment: Isn't your `WHERE` clause missing the last condition: `after the dash begin with a zero.` I don't think his sample data needs this part, since the entries that begin with a 0 also are 5 characters after the dash.

Comment: Thank you, this is great, have marked @Zorkolot as the correct answer as he answered first

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question, you have 2 main criteria in your excluded data:

1. The date is between 2019-01-01 and 2019-01-04, **AND**
2. Either the length of the `IDNum` is 5 characters (after the dash) **OR** the `IDNum` (after the dash) begins with a 0.

As with @Gordon's answer, you can wrap this up in a `NOT`:

```
WHERE NOT
(
    [DateTime] >= '2019-01-01'
    AND [DateTime] <= '2019-01-04'
    AND
    (
        IDNum LIKE '%-0%'
        OR IDnum LIKE '%-_____'
    )
)
```

With [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), we can simplify  this a bit (or at least distribute the `NOT`):

```
WHERE
(
    [DateTime] < '2019-01-01'
    OR [DateTime] > '2019-01-04'
    OR
    (
        IDNum NOT LIKE '%-0%'
        AND IDnum NOT LIKE '%-_____'
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response @Zack

Answer (score 0):

if your purpose is to meet this two following conditions:=

1. DateTime should be in between 1st January to 4th January, 2019
2. In IDNum the length of number after '-' should be more or equal than 5,
   then you probably no need of rtrim.

code:

```
Select * from Test where DateTime >= '01-01-2019' and DateTime <= '01-03-2019' and ((SUBSTRING(IDNum, 4, 1) = 0) or LEN(SUBSTRING(IDNum, 4, LEN(IDNum)-1)) >= 5);
```

though i am not sure how 31-12-2018 are present in your expected result. :D

Comment: If dealing with the datetime datatype, doing `<= '01-03-2019'` cuts of the time portion, only including datetime at midnight.  For example, it would not include 01-03-2019 06:00:00.000...  Also, OP may want times included during the 4th leading up to the 5th.  And then the intent is to exclude these datetimes.